# Find memory page ownership of cores

Tags: c, linux, caching, memory, paging

I am writing a C program on a linux machine which requires to allocate a gigantic array of 10 to 20 GBs.

After allocating the space, I want to know which core owns which pages for that array.
By "owns", I mean which core is responsible for the coherence of which page.

Is there any function or shell command to get this info?

Note: I am using Debian with gcc4.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ownership using [`move_pages()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/move_pages.2.html) or [`numa_tonode_memory()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/numa).

Comment: I am checking out move_pages which seem to be able to get the current ownership info too. It seems it will do what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate memory, the kernel usually allocates only the virtual memory; the contents (RAM pages) are only populated on the first access. And if evicted to file (file-backed memory map) or to swap (all other memory), they'll be repopulated on the next access after the eviction. This means that each page of memory allocated by a process may either not exist (it'll read as zeros in the first access, by convention), be in RAM, or be evicted (to disk or other non-RAM storage media).

On a standard multicore/multi-CPU machine, the "ownership" is determined on a cache line basis, cache lines being typically a small power of two, between 16 and 256 bytes. Each CPU "owns" the cache lines it has touched last. As the process runs, the CPU and core running the code, and thus accessing the code, changes, and thus there is no fixed "owner"; it changes dynamically. Furthermore, the management is usually done by a specific chip, memory management unit or MMU, and not by code run by the CPU. (The MMU is nowadays often integrated to the CPUs.) You can pin a process to run only on certain CPU core or cores, and based on that *guess* which CPU core owns which memory. And I guess some MMUs might have a way to report which cachelines it has given to which CPU core -- although I seriously doubt it is feasible in practice.

The entire idea of a CPU core "owning" memory is extremely strange. I don't think the Linux kernel itself even tracks which CPU core has touched which page last, it certainly does not track which CPU core has touched which cacheline last. (Tracking that would consume way too much RAM, and provide basically no benefits.)

There are distributed kernels (at least patches to the Linux kernel), and some other methods, to build up a cluster where the memory and CPUs are distributed over multiple physical machines, but appear uniform to the processes -- just as if they were running on a single physical machine. In such cases it is possible to query the management side to find out which physical node owns which CPUs and which memory pages. If that is your situation, you'll need to describe the kernel and tools you're using in detail, as the management tools vary.

Comment: Nice explanation. I am on a server machine with 4 processor chips with 8 cores in each chip, resulting a total 32 cores. I don't know much about distributed kernels. It's just regular Debian 6.0.5 . Kernel is 2.6.32 . I always thought the pages are owned by the core that touches the pages first. Isn't that true? By the way, I am trying to use pthreads with affinity for different cores to first touch different pages to distribute the ownership.

Comment: No, the ownership is at the cacheline level, and varies moment by moment. Server motherboards have extra circuitry that keeps the caches in the separate CPUs coherent, so all you see at the worst case is just a slowdown. Usually the hardware describes the topology; if it does, the Linux kernel uses it to avoid those slow CPU-to-CPU transfers, if it can. It's better to let the kernel worry about those details. Simple tests should also prove it is the best strategy.